# Blender quits when running in background

Tags: conversion

I am trying to run Blender 3d in the background, as the memory is insufficient to run the GUI (it crashes the machine). I am gathering that the memory is simply insufficient for blender - is this true?

this command :

```
 blender -b
```

allows Blender to start up initially, but then it immediately quits. I tried

```
 --debug-all --verbose 9
```

and also the bash shell command

```
 ulimit
```

... and all I can understand is the message in the shell:

```
 Blender quit
```

... am I to conclude (as I suspect) that blender will not run on this particular machine even in background mode? My real interest is to at least convert a blender file to another format (but that is for another post, perhaps).

some specs :

```
 Ubuntu 22.04.1
 Blender 3.0.1
 AMD Athlon 7450 dual-core at 1200 MHz
 MemAvailable: 2.2 gigabytes -
```

I will try this with a few fewer
programs running, such as a web browser.

Comment: I have a notebook with similar specs as well and Blender doesn't start anymore since 2.9something while on my newer, faster and better PC everything runs perfect and I'm already using version 3.3 for some time now. I cannot definitely say that it's the hardware, but I wouldn't be surprised if it was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the command line with the -b option, Blender will just open in the background, execute whatever the command line tells him to do (usually rendering or running a script) and quit.

If you don't specify any action to perform, then all it can do is open and close.
`blender -b --debug-all --verbose 9` will only open and close Blender with debug info.

The command line is merely for headless rendering, batch processing, debugging and development. It isn't meant to be a "no GUI yet fully usable version of Blender". It's not Linux.

[Command Line Arguments — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/arguments.html)

Concerning your system specs: If you only have 2GB of ram, don't expect much. Maybe try older versions, but the current requires 8.

- [Requirements — blender.org](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/)
- [Previous Versions — blender.org](https://www.blender.org/download/previous-versions/)

Comment: Though it's correct that running Blender with -b just executes whatever you give it then quits, you can do other things like boot up an RPC server then pass commands to Blender like this example https://ciesie.com/post/blender_python_rpc/